# Ruby error when creating new object: wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 0)

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby but I am currently stuck here when trying to create a new object inside a method from another class. I have this main 'command.rb' class where I just initialize its arguments:

```
class Command
 
      attr_accessor :key, :flag, :time, :bytes, :value,

      def initialize(key, flag, expTime, bytes,value)
          @key = key
          @flag = flag
          @expTime = expTime
          @bytes = bytes
          @value = value
      end
end
```

Then I try to create a Command object inside this other class:

```
require_relative 'command'

class CommandDAO

    def initialize
        @data_hash = Hash.new
    end

    def set(arrayInfo, value)
        full_key = Command.new(arrayInfo[1],arrayInfo[2],arrayInfo[3],arrayInfo[4],value)
        data_hash.store(key,full_key)
        return "STORED\r\n"
    end
end
```

The error I am getting at the moment is that the expect number of values is 0. Why is this?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: When asking a question that involves an exception having been raised it is helpful to readers if you show the actual error message and the line in which it occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma after `value`

```
      attr_accessor :key, :flag, :time, :bytes, :value,
```

It causes your initializer body to be regenerated/overwritten by `attr_accessor`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't able to spot that.